# How to portion results in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

New to AngularJS, and was wondering how I could limit results on a line, and keep spilling over onto the next row.

My page has cards loading in, based on how many people are pulled from a database.

For example: if someone searches "thomas" itll find x different thomas' and list x cards using Ng-repeat that have a name on them. But I want to limit 3 cards on a line, then move to the next row and repeat.

I cant use "LimitTo" because it just cuts off the other results.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to solve this with CSS rather than angular.

Comment: if you are using bootstrap.. let boostrap handle it for you, keep the size of card as col-md-4, which will move the 4th card on the next line and then the 7th... even if you are using some other UI framework.. you can limit no of cards on a line using the card size

Comment: @SSH was right. Not sure why I didnt think about it from as styling perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely smarter to use CSS as SSH suggested.

Simply used this and it fixed it.

```
ul{
width:100%;
}
li{
float:left;
width:45%;
margin-left: 5%;
}
```